# create a re sizable two dimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create a two dimensional array, so I can add new row each time I click the mouse..each row will represent the cursor position..

x1 y1 
x2 y2 
x3 y3
.  . 
.  . 
.  .

```
   i=0 
   private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      i++;
      x[i]=e.X;
      Y[i]=e.Y; 
     //if the array not exist create one
      int[,] numbers = new int[i, 2]{{X[i], Y[i]}};
      //if the array exist add row to the exist array
       //add the row {{X[i], Y[i]} to the array  
    }
```

Comment: Array are fixed sized. Use DataTable instead.

Comment: You should really use a structure or a class instead, `struct Pos { public int X; public int Y; }`. Also, use a List<Pos> to store them. arrays are fixed size unlike lists

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a System.Drawing.Point list. Point has both X and Y.

```
private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    points.Add(e.Location);
}
```